# How can I animate the movement of this .toggle()?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition

i have write this code for making a menu disappear and leave space for a lateral table. I've achieved what I wanted but I need to make it fancier. I noticed that when i click. before the expanding of the green div, there is a jump of position. I would like to be able to show the entire process of the movement. I've tried with a CSS `transition: all 2s` but it doesn't seem to work.

I'd love to see a slide-like global transition.

Here a fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ciaoben/6rzhu/3/)

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want... jQuery has all kinds of animation capabilities, as simple as using something like `slideUp()`: http://jsfiddle.net/AaGFs/

Comment: sorry, it was the wrong fiddle... it wasn't updated... now it is.-.. i need animation for the movement of the green div

Comment: @ciaoben Can you provide a more detailed explanation of what you want or expect? Should the green "table" expand as the blue "menu" shrinks? Or should the green "table" slide over as the blue "menu" shrinks? Having a clear, concise explanation of what is expected or what should happen might help in providing a solution that meets your needs perfectly.

Comment: i would like to see the green "table" slide while the blue menu disappear!  globally i would like to achieve something similar:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/

Answer (score 0):

**Final update:**

Still not a perfect solution, but this should be good enough to get you going.  I gotta get to my own work after this though.  I used a container class and threw CSS transitions on the sub-elements.  Then just a simple `.toggleClass()` on the `.container`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rzhu/8/)

**Update:**

*If* you include jQuery UI (which I don't recommend if you don't need), then `.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, and `.toggleClass()` take a second parameter for a duration like in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rzhu/5/).

Otherwise, you are best off relying on CSS transitions. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rzhu/6/) (could definitely be cleaned up, but works):

```
.aa {
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
    -moz-transition: width 1s;
    -o-transition: width 1s;
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

---

Straight from the jQuery [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) documentation:

```
.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
  duration (default: 400)
  Type: Number or String
  A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
```

You can add a time for how long the animation takes.  Here I have set it for 1 second:

```
$('.sidebar').on('click',function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggle(1000);    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rzhu/1/)

Comment: sorry, but i noticed that the fiddle was the wrong one! it 's more complex the real example, i've updated the fiddle now. The animation that i need is on the green div, and later gloabally.

Comment: excuse me, but it doens't solve my problem.... i still see the green div "jumping" from the initial position to the final one.-- i would like to see it moving instead of jumping... (globally i would like to see something like this:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/5/)

Comment: That'll probably be a lot more difficult.  I think you'll need to have a global container with one class change that goes from one state to the other..then you can put a transition on this class change.  Right now you have to change two classes (two different animations) independently, and make sure the animations line up perfectly.

Comment: Can you show me an example of that in my fiddle? i've tried but i cant.. i've tried to use the container div.. but no result